# pyinstaller can't find pyinstaller.exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, errno

I was having trouble running some code as a .exe file when I used pyinstaller, it wouldn't find the module Crypto even though it successfully turned into a .exe file(I am using pycrypto if that helps) so I changed my imports from

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA26
```

to

```
import Crypto
from Crypto import Hash
from Crypto.Hash import SHA26
```

I then tried again using

```
pyinstaller DONT_RUN.py -F --debug
```

but now it just gives me the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\pyinstaller.exe\\__main__.pyo'
```

I tried listing Crypto as a hidden import and it didn't work

I don't mind if the current issue doesn't get resolved I just want to be able to run the file as a .exe file so if i just need to do something else please say so.

Comment: What is the python version?

Comment: @error404 python 3.7

Comment: Run you command without "--debug"